# include chain of thought in LLM reAct agent response

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

First of all let me say that I know the two examples of indirect tax below are too simple and incorrect.  This is a toy example where I'm trying to expose the COT reasoning the reAct agent is using.  So I'm only allowing two possibilities for indirect tax.  That said what I really want to see is the Thought -> Observation -> Action pattern the LLM is following to answer the question.  I have my python 3 code below, along with the output I'm getting.  The LLM just seems to be taking the action and returning the final output without going through a chain of thought.

I would like to see a chain of thought like:

question="""Walmart sells 25 cases of product to Wendy for a sale amount of $61.  What tax is owed by Walmart from this transaction?"""

thought: Walmart is a business selling to a customer.
observation: sales tax is owed.
action: sales_tax[sale amount $61]
...

Am I miss understanding something about the prompt formatting for reAct?  If so, how should I restructure the prompt to get the right cot?  Or is there a setting I'm missing, (I thought verbose would do it.)

Also I noticed if I set the ConversationBufferWindowMemory with k higher than 1, if I re-run the same question I'll get significantly different response, even though I have temperature=0.  Does anyone know why that would be?  I want my responses to be pretty consitent.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# chat agent

from config import api_key,new_personal_api_key

# apikey=api_key

apikey=new_personal_api_key

import os

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = apikey



from langchain.agents import Tool

def sales_tax(string):
    
    sale_amount=float(string.split(" ")[2].replace("$",""))
        
    result = 0.1*sale_amount
    
    return str(result)


sales_tax_tool = Tool(
    name='sales_tax',
    func= sales_tax,
    description="Useful for when you need to calculate sales tax owed by a business when they sell a product to a customer. The input to this tool should be a string describing the amount of the sale.  For example 'sale amount $45'. "
)

def customer_use_tax(string):
    
    sale_amount=float(string.split(" ")[2].replace("$",""))
        
    result = 0.05*sale_amount
    
    return str(result)


customer_use_tax_tool = Tool(
    name='customer_use_tax',
    func= customer_use_tax,
    description="Useful for when you need to calculate customer user tax owed by a customer when they purchase a product from a business. The input to this tool should be a string describing the amount of the sale.  For example 'sale amount $45'. "
)


from langchain import OpenAI 
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

# Set up the turbo LLM
turbo_llm = ChatOpenAI(
    temperature=0,
    model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo'
)


from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory


tools = [sales_tax_tool,customer_use_tax_tool]

# conversational agent memory
memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(
    memory_key='chat_history',
    k=1,
    return_messages=True
)


# create our agent
conversational_agent = initialize_agent(
    agent='chat-conversational-react-description',
    tools=tools,
    llm=turbo_llm,
#     llm=local_llm,
    verbose=True,
    max_iterations=3,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
    memory=memory,
    handle_parsing_errors=True
)


question="""Walmart sells 25 cases of product to Wendy for a sale amount of $61.  What tax is owed by Walmart from this transaction?"""


manual_react = manual_react = f"""
You are a tax preparer calculating the tax owed from transactions between businesses and customers.  There are two possible types of taxes that can be owed from these transactions.  sales tax is owed by a business when it sells a product to a customer.  customer use tax is owed by a customer when they purchase a product from a business.  Please only consider these instructions and the examples below when trying to calculate the tax owed.

Question: Safeway sold 40 units of a product to Jim for a sale amount of $55, what tax is owed by safeway?
Thought: Safeway is a business selling a product to a customer named Jim therefore sales tax is owed from the sale.  The sale amount is $55.
Action: sales_tax_tool['sale amount $55']
Observation: 5.5.
Thought: The tax owed is $5.5.
Action: Finish[The tax owed is $5.5.]

Question: Jen bought 10 units of a product from Amazon for a sale amount of $15, what tax is owed by Jen?
Thought: Jen is a customer buying a product from a business named Amazon therefore customer use tax is owed from the sale.  The sale amount is $15.
Action: customer_use_tax_tool['sale amount $15']
Observation: o.75.
Thought: The tax owed is $0.75.
Action: Finish[The tax owed is $0.75.]

Question:{question}"""


conversational_agent(manual_react)
```

Output:

````
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
```json
{
    "action": "sales_tax",
    "action_input": "sale amount $61"
}
```
Observation: 6.1000000000000005
Thought:```json
{
    "action": "Final Answer",
    "action_input": "The tax owed by Walmart from the transaction is $6.10."
}
```

> Finished chain.

{'input': "\nYou are a tax preparer calculating the tax owed from transactions between businesses and customers.  There are two possible types of taxes that can be owed from these transactions.  sales tax is owed by a business when it sells a product to a customer.  customer use tax is owed by a customer when they purchase a product from a business.  Please only consider these instructions and the examples below when trying to calculate the tax owed.\n\nQuestion: Safeway sold 40 units of a product to Jim for a sale amount of $55, what tax is owed by safeway?\nThought: Safeway is a business selling a product to a customer named Jim therefore sales tax is owed from the sale.  The sale amount is $55.\nAction: sales_tax_tool['sale amount $55']\nObservation: 5.5.\nThought: The tax owed is $5.5.\nAction: Finish[The tax owed is $5.5.]\n\nQuestion: Jen bought 10 units of a product from Amazon for a sale amount of $15, what tax is owed by Jen?\nThought: Jen is a customer buying a product from a business named Amazon therefore customer use tax is owed from the sale.  The sale amount is $15.\nAction: customer_use_tax_tool['sale amount $15']\nObservation: o.75.\nThought: The tax owed is $0.75.\nAction: Finish[The tax owed is $0.75.]\n\nQuestion:Walmart sells 25 cases of product to Wendy for a sale amount of $61.  What tax is owed by Walmart from this transaction?",
 'chat_history': [],
 'output': 'The tax owed by Walmart from the transaction is $6.10.'}
````